# 'no module named' error even though I installed module in virtual environment and it works fine on localhost

Tags: python, flask, module, python-import

I recently got a server through DigitalOcean and I'm playing around with a Flask App.

The app works perfectly fine on my computer when I run it locally. But it doesn't work when hosted on DigitalOcean. Both Virtual Environments are the same.

When I do 'pip freeze', the output is:

```
coverage==4.0.3
dominate==2.1.16
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.5.7
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
gunicorn==19.4.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
visitor==0.1.2
Werkzeug==0.11.3
wheel==0.24.0
WTForms==2.1
```

But I get an error when I look in Apache error log:

> ImportError: No module named flask.ext.bootstrap

I'm not sure why it can't find it. Like I said, it works fine on my computer when I run it locally.

I also tried 'from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap' instead of 'from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap'. Both works locally, but neither work on DigitalOcean server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running the application in DigitalOcean? Are you sure you're using the gunicorn that's inside the virtual environment?

Comment: Actually I'm not using gunicorn. I'm pretty sure I added gunicorn by mistake. I followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

When I run it from the virtualenv on the VM (by calling 'python \_\_init\_\_.py'), the app works when I visit: <IP ADDRESS>:5000.

Comment: Because you are using the Python inside your visual environment. If you are using mod_wsgi, what does your Apache configuration look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making Flask Apps using digitalocean, this tutorial is a lot more up to date and simpler than the one I posted above:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I did the process again, but this time using gunicorn and nginx and found the overall process a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how you configured Apache. It's probably using the system default Python without your virtual env.

Comment: I added the line

_activate_this = '/var/www/<FlaskApp>/<FlaskApp>/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'_

In my .wsgi file. I thought that would cover it.

Comment: Shouldn't the activate file be `source`d? I mostly use virtualenvwrapper so can't remember, sorry.